# Why section isn't respecting the height but is respecting the widht of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I've the following html code:

```css
 .generalGrid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 0.6fr 1.4fr;
      grid-column-gap: 1vh;
      grid-row-gap: 1vh;
}

.generalGrid > div {
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
}

.tournament {
  height: 24vh;
  max-height: 24vh;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.team {
  height: 50vh;
  max-height: 50vh;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.fss {
  height: 24vh;
  max-height: 24vh;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.squad {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;

}

.substitutesFlex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  height: 20vh;
  max-height: 20vh;
  margin-top: 1vh;

}

.container {
  height: 50vh;
  max-height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: #f55555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<section class="generalGrid">
  <div class="tournament" ></div>
  <div class="team"></div>
  <div class="fss" ></div>
  <div class="squad" ></div>
</section>
<section class="substitutesFlex">
  <div class="substitutes"></div>
</section>
</div>
```

I don't know why the sections inside the div "container" respects only the width but they don't respect height limits.

I've read some posts about the define the height and max-height of parent but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the overflow rule of container so that the container has to hide the div's that are overflowing or show a scrollbar.

putting `overflow: auto` in `.container` class does the job.

also if you are expecting the container content to not over flow.
Then you will need to give the children height in `%` not in `vh` because the `vh` always means the virtual height of `window or viewport`.

You need to remove the height and max height of the grid items and give height to to the `.generalGrid` and the `.substitutesFlex` in `%` not in `vh`.

```css
.generalGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.6fr 1.4fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1%;
  grid-row-gap: 1%;
  height: 80%
}

.generalGrid > div {
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
}

.tournament {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.team {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.fss {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.squad {
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  
}

.substitutesFlex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  height: 20%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  
}

.container {
  height: 50vh;
  max-height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: #f55555;
  //overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="generalGrid">
    <div class="tournament" ></div>
    <div class="team"></div>
    <div class="fss" ></div>
    <div class="squad" ></div>
  </section>
  <section class="substitutesFlex">
    <div class="substitutes"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: The `vh` unit refers to the *viewport* (can be the window, or the screen in fullscreen mode), not to the document

Comment: @Johannes sorry. Actually that is what I meant. window not document. :)

Comment: @anees overflow: auto isn't what I want. I need it to be responsive, like, ajust the same layout inside the container... I've tried define the children height in percentage but doing this makes the layout looks really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the .container and section height in `vh` a unit only dependent on the window height, so it does it exactly as you ordered. This is a case of units and maths.
I write css and html better than English - look at the snipped, with any question drop a comment.

```css
body{ background: #555; text-align: center}
.box{
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
.grid{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 0.6fr 1.4fr;
grid-column-gap: 1vh;
grid-row-gap: 1vh;
background: #fff;
}
.one{
height: 12.5vh;
grid-column: 1;
background: red;
}
.two{
height: 25vh;
grid-column: 1;
background: gold;
}
.three{
height: 12.5vh;
grid-column: 1;
background: #0d0;
}
.four{
height: 100%;
grid-column: 2;
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 4;
background: #adf
}
.five{
background: plum
}
.flex {
display: flex;
height: 20vh;
margin-top: 1vh;
background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<section class="grid">
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="three">three - to long content will break fixed sizes</div>
<div class="four">four <p>grid is still not fully supported</p><p>grid does not mean responsive</p></div>
</section>
<section class="flex">
<div class="five">five</div>
<div>flex does not mean responsive</div>
</section>
</div>
<p>and what you gonna do with other half?</p>
```

- with `%` and `height` is small problem - 100% works good, other values unexpected wrong.